# Accessing the Jersey resource object in a MessageBodyReader/Writer

Tags: jersey, jax-ws

I have the following resource in Jersey:

```
@Path("/my-resource")
@Produces("application/xml")
public class MyResource {

    @Path("/result")
    public MyResponse result() {
        return new MyResponse();
    }

}
```

I now want to write a MessageBodyReader/Writer that uses different means to serialize/deserialize the MyResponse object depending on a property of the MyResource used to create the response (the plan is to have two MyResource instances for different API versions, and serialize them differently).

The question now is how to access the MyResource instance that handles the request in Jersey? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to access `MyResource`, just implement `MessageBodyReader` / `MessageBodyWriter` for your `MyResponse` class and register them with your `ObjectMapper` instance.

If you don't know how to access your `ObjectMapper` look up `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>`.

Hope that helps.